# run a program as a service when it is called in the python script

Tags: python

I have a small GUI which can start a program(pre installed application) as a subprocess in a thread, but now i want the program to run as a service when i press a button in the GUI.

Can i daemonise the subprocess. If it is not possible how can i do that?

The code for GUI is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import Tkinter as tk

import subprocess
import os
import signal
import threading


class StageGui:
    process=0
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.process = None
        self.f = tk.Frame(main, width=300, height=300)
        self.b1=tk.Button(main,text='Start Medina',command=startmedina).pack(side='left',anchor='nw')
        self.b2=tk.Button(main,text='Quit Medina',command=quitmedina).pack(side='left',anchor='nw')
        self.xf = tk.Frame(self.f,relief='groove', borderwidth=2)

    class myThread (threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.threadID = threadID
            self.name = name
            self.counter = counter
        def run(self):
            StageGui.process=subprocess.Popen(['pre xx'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True,preexec_fn=os.setsid)
            return
def startmedina():
    thread1 = StageGui.myThread(1, "Thread-1", 1)
    thread1.start()
    print "Exiting Main Thread"
    return

main = tk.Tk()
stagegui=StageGui(main)
main.title('prototype')
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does it need to be a true daemon, ie keep running after you close your python app. Or, do you just need it to run in the background as long as your GUI is still going?

Comment: i need the app to run as a service as long as  until i quit the GUI @anders

Comment: In that case you should basically already be done. Just connect a button to spin myThread when you click it. Did you already try that and run into problems?

Comment: @anders what do you mean by spin myThread? i don't know it can you tell me how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this as an answer since it's easier to post code this way, but it doesn't really address your original question. You might want to update your question based on our comments and this answer.

"Spinning a thread" just means creating a thread and starting it, which you're doing with this code:

```
thread1 = StageGui.myThread(1, "Thread-1", 1)
thread1.start()
```

You just need to change your code to do that in your button handler. I'm not familiar with tkinter, but it should be something like:

```
def button_handler():
    thread1 = StageGui.myThread(1, "Thread-1", 1)
    thread1.start()

b = Button(main, text="Spin Thread", command=button_handler)
b.pack()
```

That needs to happen after you do:

```
main = tk.Tk()
```